# MySQL ORDER_BY partial Integer in String

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I have a series of varchar fields in a MySQL database that are "numbered":

```
+-----------+
| name      |
+-----------+
|  thing 1  |
|  thing 2  |
|  thing 3  |
|  ...      |
|  thing 10 |
|  thing 11 |
+-----------+
```

I want to order them as listed above. However, a simple `ORDER_BY table.name` produces something like the following:

```
thing 1
thing 10
thing 11
thing 2
thing 3
...
```

This makes some sense, since MySQL is treating the entire field as a String (varchar). However, I've tried numerous methods to sort including `CAST(name AS DECIMAL)` and `name + 0`. This will *only* sort by the decimal part, ignoring the string part. None of these work because I need to sort by `name` *first* and *then* sort by the trailing decimal.

I tried `ORDER_BY name, name + 0`, but nothing seems to work. How do I perform and `ORDER_BY` and then `ORDER_BY` within that subset? (I think that will work).

Comment: put a 0 infront of the 1 so it's 01, 02, 03 in the data.  if that's not an option, break out the left and right into separate fields, if that's not an option substring out the left and right parts in the order by then order first by the left part then the right part (casting it to an int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have two sorts - first by the `name` part, and second by the numeric part, like this:

```
order by left(name,instr(name,' ')),cast(right(name,instr(name,' ')+1) as decimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function SUBSTRING_INDEX can split the string.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1) AS a, CAST(SUBSTRING(name, ' ', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS b
FROM t
ORDER BY a, b
```